# How to apply the Renderer text() function multiple times to a Highcharts chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to **add multiple Renderer text() functions to a Highcharts chart**, but I'm not having any luck.

The first function populates on the chart correctly, but the second does not.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Here's what my code looks like at the moment:

```js
}, function (chart) {
        chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: red; font-weight:bold">Test</span>', 331, 41) 
        
        .css({
            fontSize: '12px'
        })
        .add();
        });           
   
    },  function (chart) {
        chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: red; font-weight:bold">(10)</span>', 331, 33) 
        
        .css({
            fontSize: '11px'
        })
        .add();
        });
```

Comment: What is the function you are wrapping `chart.renderer.text` in? That looks weird.

Comment: More information and a live demo would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to put two callbacks, which is incorrect. Use single one and then put both renderers.

```
}, function (chart) {
        chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: red; font-weight:bold">Test</span>', 331, 41) 

        .css({
            fontSize: '12px'
        })
        .add();
        });           

        chart.renderer.text('<span style="color: red; font-weight:bold">(10)</span>', 331, 33) 

        .css({
            fontSize: '11px'
        })
        .add();
});
```